# Distance covered by two object from different initial point

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two cars, an Edsel and a Studebaker, are 635 kilometers apart, with Edsel moving behind Studebaker(otherwise they won't never meet, by the speeds given). They start at the same time and drive in one direction . The Edsel travels at a rate of $70$ kilometers per hour and the Studebaker travels $57$ 
kilometers per hour. In how many hours will the two cars meet?

Comment: how many km are removed from the remaining distance every hour ? then apply cross-muiltiplication.

Comment: Divide the total distance traveled by the total distance the two cars travel in one hour.

Comment: Depending upon what direction they are traveling they may not meet but in other direction they will meet.  At that time what will the impact be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edsel will have to cover $635$ kilometers faster compared to Studebaker in order to meet him. Further, he's moving $70-57=13$ km/h faster than Studebaker. So, he'll meet Studebaker in:
$$T=\frac{635\text{km}}{13\text{km/hr}}=\boxed{48.846\text{ hr}}$$